# Print all alternating nodes of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to go through a linked list and print all the alternating nodes at once. I'm not allowed to create a second list/array to store all the alternate nodes values. So far I have been able to go through the alternating nodes with the code below. However it will keep printing the value as it is looping through the nodes...

let's say the list is [1, 2, 3, 4]

```c
NodeT *p;
NodeT *a;
p = list;
while (p != NULL)
{
    printf("p is %d-->", p->data);
    a = p->next;
    printf("a is %d-->", a->data);
    p = p->next->next;
}
```

The current result is:
p is 1-->a is 2-->p is 3-->a is 4-->

The result that I'm looking for is:

p is 1-->3
a is 2-->4

is there any way to achieve this without creating any new list/array?

Comment: The question does not make any sense. There is no reason to have a separate `p` and `a`. If you want that output you could just keep track whether it last printed `p` or `a` and swap that each time. If you need separate values, then you could keep a pointer to a pointer, that alternates between pointing to `p` and `a`. But then again, that is similar to `p` and `a` being an array `p[0]` and `p[1]` and using `p[some_counter++ & 1]`. I don't really see how this is a useful exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the pointer `p` and check that `a` is not `NULL` before accessing the fields of `a`.

Here is a modified version:

```
void print_alternating_nodes(NodeT *list) {
    NodeT *p;
    NodeT *a;
    p = list;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("p is %d --> ", p->data);
        a = p = p->next;
        if (a) {
            printf("a is %d --> ", a->data);
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hope to produce that output with one loop, since you want to print first *all* nodes at odd positions, and only after that all nodes at *even* positions. So use two loops, or even better: create a function that does the looping and printing, and call it twice -- once with `list` and a second time with `list->next`:

```
void printAlternating(NodeT *p) {
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d-->", p->data);
        p = p->next;
        if (p == NULL) break;
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}
```

Use the above function as follows:

```
    printf("p is ");
    printAlternating(list);
    printf("a is ");
    printAlternating(list == NULL ? NULL : list->next);
```

#### A fully working program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} NodeT;

NodeT *createNode(int data, NodeT *next) {
    NodeT *p = malloc(sizeof (NodeT));
    p->data = data;
    p->next = next;
    return p;
}

void printAlternating(NodeT *p) {
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d-->", p->data);
        p = p->next;
        if (p == NULL) break;
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

int main() {
    NodeT *list = createNode(1, 
                  createNode(2,
                  createNode(3,
                  createNode(4, NULL))));

    printf("p is ");
    printAlternating(list);
    printf("a is ");
    printAlternating(list == NULL ? NULL : list->next);
}
```

Output:

```
p is 1-->3-->NULL
a is 2-->4-->NULL
```

Comment: well, this is what I have been doing so far, however, the question said that I'm not allowed to traverse through the list twice nor creating another list to store the value. I'm thinking would it implies that I will have to reshuffle all the alternating nodes and put them to the first half of the list and the second half of the list will have the remaining nodes? And then workout where is the middle of the list and print them out? - But then again, by doing this I'm still required to traverse through the list more than just 1 time and it is also much more complicated...

Comment: This "restriction" (not traverse twice) was not specified in your question. What *are* you allowed to do? Recursion? Mutation? Store output in strings first and then print the strings? .... Any other restrictions?

Comment: Thank you. I just realized now that this information is missing from the question. There are two conditions that I'm not allowed to do:
1. I cannot traverse the list twice
2. I cannot create any extra list or array to store the vallue

Comment: I would suggest you quote the code challenge literally in your question, so that there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to edit my post but somehow I couldn't...Also, the way you use the createNode function in the main() is something new to me. Thank you for that :)

Comment: I see someone has voted for a minor edit to your question. I'm afraid you'll have to wait it gets accepted before you can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Done using c++ list (to save having to write a list implemenatin) but same idea can be done in c. Just read ahead a bit.

```
std::list<int> l{1,2,3,4,5,6};
auto it = l.begin();
int a = *it++; // should really test for 0 or 1 element only in list
int b = *it++;

while (it != l.end())
{
    int c = *it++;
    std::cout << a << "->" << c << "\n";
    a = b;
    b = c;
}
```

output

```
1->3
2->4
3->5
4->6
```